# Ubuntu 20.04 no sound from Motherboard

Tags: 20.04, sound, realtek, gigabyte

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I have no sound, even if I try it from the CD. For now, I tried to reinstall pulseaudio and alsamixer, but I still have no sound. The only sound I can get, is, if I plug in my headphones to my yeti microphone, but no sound is coming from the audio port on my motherboard.

My motherboard: X58A-UD3R
Its audio chip: Realtek ALC889

In the settings / sound I have four output devices, but none of them lead to my speakers. I have:

- HDMI / DisplayPort 2 - GP104 High Definition Audio Controller
- Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built in Audio
- Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Yeti Stereo Microphone
- Speakers - Yeti Stereo Microphone

but in alsamixer, I think I see the audio port that is supposed to work, see

[image: screenshot]

and here with pavucontrol

[image: pavucontrol]

A few years ago, I know, that I installed ubuntu(probably ubuntu 10) and there was no audio, but this was solved easily and now I'm struggling.

Comment: Do you get sound via your TV (i.e. `HDMI / DisplayPort 2 - GP104 High Definition Audio Controller`) or system speaker (i.e. `Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built in Audio`)? I am thinking that if you do, that will mean your sound drivers are good and the issue may be due to connection to your speaker?

Comment: Yes if i plug a TV and select the HDMI / DisplayPort 2 - GP104 High Definition Audio Controller the audio work on the TV, but no sound from the speaker. If i select Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built in Audio there is no sound (from the TV and speakers). With windows i only need to unplug and replug the audio cable to the port and windows(or realtek) detect it automaticly, but it doesnt work with ubuntu

Comment: _Yes if i plug a TV and select the HDMI / DisplayPort 2 - GP104 High Definition Audio Controller the audio work on the TV, but no sound from the speaker_ This is to be expected.  Sound should only come out from your speaker if you plug it the speakers to the output port of the TV. If your speaker is connected to your computer, you should not expect any sound to come out of it.

Comment: When `Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built in Audio` is selected, Ubuntu should direct the sound to exit from the speakers that are connected to the computer. Do check the wire connections of your speaker to your PC are in the correct socket(s). Also, ensure your speakers are working first by testing it on another system.

Comment: Go to Ubuntu's `Settings` --> `Sound` and for `Output` select  `Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built in Audio`. Next click on `Test Speakers` button (it is at the bottom) to test your speaker.

Comment: Then i guess ubuntu is failing at directing the sound to the speakers sockets since its not working and everything i plugged correctly. 
Thank you for your time spend on this Sun Bear

Comment: It is strange given that you can direct the sound signal to your TV sound system via HDMI but not to the audio port on your mother board. Do u also have another OS installed (e.g. Windows/other Linux distro) to the same system that is accessible at Grub or via Virtualbox? Have you tried to see if these other OS can play sound out to your audio jack? If they work, then likely your Ubuntu installation has an issue and it might be worth reinstalling Ubuntu. Make sure your Ubuntu version is downloaded correctly.

Comment: i reinstalled ubuntu (this time without connecting it to the internet) and still i have no sound. I'm pretty sure at this point that my motherboard is just not fully compatible with ubuntu.

Comment: You probably want an internet connection. This way, you can run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` to ensure your newly installed Ubuntu has the latest drives/files. Your mb is at least 10 years old. I do not know if that is causing this issue. If it is, a dated alternative that I could think of is to install Ubuntu 18.04 to see if your sound issue is resolved. The disadvantage of this approach is its hardware and maintenance updates cycle life has ended. However, its maintenance update life will still persist to 2023, i.e. you can use it for 1 plus more years.

Comment: Recognizably, the ideal solution would be to understand the cause of your issue. Maybe missing a suitable driver? Hopefully, someone more experienced in this area can help you. Meanwhile, if u choose to use Ubuntu 20.04, it seems your current option is to plug your speaker to your TV, connect your TV to the computer via HDMI and enjoy the sound that way. ;)

Comment: Can you select `Line Out - Built in Audio` instead of `Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built in Audio`? This works when your speaker is plugged into the normal phone jack that is green in colour. `Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built in Audio` will not give out sound.

Comment: There is no 'Line Out - Built in Audio'

There is no sound in Ubuntu 18.04, but the sound work in Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Good news, i managed to have sound but when i reboot it didn't save anything. If i go in pavucontrol - configuration and change the Built-In Audio profile from (Digital Stereo Duplex (IEC958)) to (Analog Surround 5.1 Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input) it work but won't save

Comment: and if i open ex; a new webpage i need to go in pavucontrol - Playback and change the source of the application to Built-in Audio Analog Surround 5.1 instead of GP104 High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI2) each time to get sound in the application. In my sound setting the output device selected is the HDMI and if i change it to Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built in Audio there is no more sound and needed to go back in pavucontrol configuration and change the Built-in Audio profile again.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.04, open `Settings` and set `Output Device` to `Line Out - Built in Audio`. Don't use Digital Output given that you are using the normal analogue jack.

Next set `Configuration` to `Analogue Stereo Output` or `Analogue Surround #.# Output` (which ever that suits you) if you are using more than 2 speakers. You can click the Test button to discover what works best for you.

[image: sound setting]

Comment: In the settings / sound I have two output devices, but none of them lead to my speakers. I have: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 - GP104 High Definition Audio Controller -and- Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built in Audio.   There is no Line Out - Built-in Audio

Comment: Can you provide a photo of your setup and connections in your question? Also, I am a little confuse. Your wrote earlier that `Built-in Audio Analog Surround 5.1 ` works but now you do not see it but you see `HDMI / DisplayPort 2 - GP104 High Definition Audio Controller` and `Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built in Audio`. Can you clarify?

Comment: https://ibb.co/9Y94BMC  
https://ibb.co/1qcCBYP  
https://ibb.co/Zzh83Bd
 These are some screenshot, hope it help you understand. The Built-in Audio Analog Surround 5.1 is only available in pavucontrol. (and how did you grey out some lines like Built-in Audio Analog Surround 5.1)

Comment: Hardware-wise? The part that connects to your computer. Also, must you use pavucontrol?

Comment: Hardware-wise...the green is plugged in the green, the black in the black and the orange in the orage...yes to have sound i must use pavucontrol each time

Comment: `green` for `LINE OUT`,  `black` for `REAR` and `orange` for `C/SUB`. If that is the case, these are all analogue signal. Furthermore, your `SPDIF OUT` is not connect. Why r you getting `Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built in Audio`? You should only see `Line Out - Built in Audio`. Is your computer plug to a TV and that is why u see `HDMI / DisplayPort 2 - GP104 High Definition Audio`?Controller`

Comment: What happens if you uninstall pavucontrol? By default, Ubuntu 20.04 Sound Setting should be sufficient to manage such simple sound connections.

Comment: I don't know why i'm getting Difital Output (S/PDIF) - Built in Audio and not the Line Out one. The HDMI / Displayport should be my monitor (my VR headset is plugged into the other other HDMI port of my GPU but even if i disconnect it, it doesn't change anything)
If i uninstall pavucontrol i have no sound since is the only way i found to get sound, Ubuntu 20.04 settings are clearly not sufficient to manage the sound connection of my motherboard.